# Calculate time difference (Subtract the time range 10PM to 9AM) between two datetime fields using django annotate?

Tags: django, postgresql, python-datetime, django-annotate

I have to calculate the time difference between to DateTime fields, also keeping in mind to subtract the time frame 10 PM-9 AM for each transaction if it lies in.

The following code snippet saves the duration between those two fields but I'm unable to subtract the time frame 10 PM-9 AM from that duration for further use.

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, DurationField

MyModel.objects.annotate(
     diff=ExpressionWrapper(F('field1') - F('field2'), output_field=DurationField())
)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Could you give examples on what you try to achieve?

Comment: @ha-neul I want to have the time difference for some use cases but this time difference shouldn't contain any time between the range of 10 PM-9 AM. That's why I want to subtract it from the calculated time difference. Now have you got some idea?